# Trouble filtering data in Dynamics 365 using the oData query with JSON API - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: json, api, odata, dynamics-365

Good morning
I'm currently trying to filter data from Dynamics 365 and facing a lot of issues filtering data.
I need to filter data from a column. I only want data with character '_'.

Here is my request`$filter=contains(AccountDisplayValue,'_')`
This request return this error:
 `"message": "The type 'System.String' for the query operator is not Queryable!",`

Thanks of your precious help

I try to filter data in oData query.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is this F&O can you confirm ? Show the complete endpoint, sample data and more context like api version for getting better assistance